# PyQt4 - Distinguish Window Resizing from Animation Resizing

Tags: python, events, animation, resize, pyqt4

I need to catch a resize event in my PyQt4 application.

However, I need to know whether the resizing was triggered by code (or the User), or is due to a QPropertyAnimation.
Is there anyway to differentiate the two?

Something like...

```
event.isAnimation()
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You can always put a flag where you initiate the animation though.

Comment: True, but then wouldn't I have to multithread to set the flag back when the animation finishes? (Or use a QTimer of equal duration to the animation)?

Are there signals emmitted when an animation ends I could instead use?

Comment: Yes, there is a `finished()` signal for [`Q*Animation`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractanimation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check the `QEvent::spontaneous()` property ? It return True if the resize is originated from a system event, otherwise return False.

Comment: The function doesn't discriminate between animation resizing and coded resizing; just user vs code. Is there a way to block the resizeEvent being triggered during animation?